# cannot use if inside map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React component allows to sequentially upload text file to display their contents on the page. The contents is being accumulated to the state inside the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` call. The various keys inside that call are the keys from the uploaded text files.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getFile } from '../actions/fileActions';
import toJsonArray from '../utils/toJsonArray';

class TableInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      file: {},
      'Incurred Date': [],
      'Memo': [],
      'Person Name': [],
      'Amount': [],
      'Billable': [],
      'Entry Date': [],
      'Comment': [],
      type: [],
      length: 0
    };

    this.onFileUpload = this.onFileUpload.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('nextProps:', nextProps);

    const { file } = nextProps.file;

    if (file) {
      this.setState({ file });
    }

    if (file) {
      let readFromFile;

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = event => {
        readFromFile = event.target.result;

        const jsonArray = toJsonArray(readFromFile);

        this.setState({
          'Incurred Date': this.state['Incurred Date'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Incurred Date'])),
          'Memo': this.state['Memo'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Memo'])),
          'Person Name': this.state['Person Name'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Person Name'])),
          'Amount': this.state['Amount'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Amount'])),
          'Billable': this.state['Billable'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Billable'])),
          'Entry Date': this.state['Entry Date'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Entry Date'])),
          'Comment': this.state['Comment'].concat(jsonArray.map(item => item['Comment'])),
          length: this.state.length + jsonArray.length,
          type: this.state.type.concat(Array(jsonArray.length).fill(file.name === 'expenses.csv' ? 'Expense' : 'Time'))
        });
      };

      reader.onerror = error => console.log(error);
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  }

  onFileUpload() {
    const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

    this.props.getFile(file);
  }

  render() {
    let rows = [];

    if (this.state.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.length; i++) {
        rows.push(
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{this.state['Person Name'] && this.state['Person Name'][i]}</td>
            <td>{this.state['Amount'] && this.state['Amount'][i]}</td>
            {this.state['Memo'] && this.state['Memo'][i] && <td>{this.state['Memo'][i]}</td>}
            {this.state['Comment'] && this.state['Comment'][i] && <td>{this.state['Comment'][i]}</td>}
            {this.state['Incurred Date'] && this.state['Incurred Date'][i] && <td>{this.state['Incurred Date'][i]}</td>}
            {this.state['Entry Date'] && this.state['Entry Date'][i] && <td>{this.state['Entry Date'][i]}</td>}
            <td>{this.state['Billable'] && this.state['Billable'][i]}</td>
            <td>{this.state.type && this.state.type[i]}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
    }

    let totalAmountExpense = this.state['Amount'] && this.state['Amount'].map((item, i) => {
      let total = 0;
      if (this.state.type[i] === 'Expenses') {
        total += parseInt(this.state['Amount'][i], 10);
      }

      return total;
    }).reduce((total, num) => parseInt(total, 10) + parseInt(num, 10), 0);

    const totalAmount = this.state['Amount'] && this.state['Amount'].reduce((total, num) => parseInt(total, 10) + parseInt(num, 10), 0);

    return (
      <div>
        <table className='table-input'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Billable</th>
              <th>Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {rows}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Total Amount: {totalAmount}</p>
        <p>Total Amount for Expense: {totalAmountExpense}</p>
        <label htmlFor='files' className='file-input-label'>Select File</label>
        <input type='file' id='files' className='file-input-hidden' onChange={this.onFileUpload} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  file: state.file
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getFile })(TableInput);
```

`const totalAmount` is calculated and displayed Ok. `let totalAmountExpense` is not. Seems the `if` call inside `map()` isn't called. `totalAmountExpense` is supposed to calculate the total Amount for the type `Expense`.

How do I get `totalAmountExpense` to be calculated and displayed?

Comment: Of course you can use `if` inside a `.map()` callback. Have you verified that the condition in the `if` statement is satisfied?

Comment: I tried `console.log('this.type.expense:', this.state.type[i] === 'Expense')` as the first line inside `map()`. It fired and returned a proper boolean.

Comment: You test for a value of 'Expenses', but you set a value of 'Expense' ;)

Comment: Also there's no need to call `parseInt()` on values that are already numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well on the bright side the resolution was simple. The credit goes to @Jaxx.

Changing from `if (this.state.type[i] === 'Expenses')` to `if (this.state.type[i] === 'Expense')` inside the `map()` call fixed it.

Comment: As a quick aside, this demonstrates why using constants like `EXPENSE` (which you would define either in a `constants.js` file imported into your components, or at the beginning of a component file) is better than using strings like `'Expense'`. Comparing to a non-existing constant would trigger a linting error.